# Which code i can add to take data for saved posts using instaloader? Python

Tags: python, instaloader

Which code i can add to this code to get information about data to each saved post using instalouder? Please help!

```
import instaloader
```

def save_insta_collection():

```
username = 'cursach2022'
loader = instaloader.Instaloader()
loader.load_session_from_file(username)

profile = instaloader.Profile.from_username(loader.context, username)

post_list = []
try:
    for saved_photos in profile.get_saved_posts():
        post_list.append(saved_photos)

    loader.download_post(post_list[0], 'mysavedcollection')

except IndexError:
    print('You have no saved posts.')

save_insta_collection()
```

save_insta_collection()

Comment: *sorry, date to each saved post